# Mouse Listener Cannot Find Symbol (image)

Tags: java

I am trying to build a (my first) simple game in Java. If a user clicks on this image, it will add to their score. As you can see, I am trying to add a mouseListener to imgcloud, but I am getting this error - **'error: cannot find symbol imgCloud.addMouseListener ( this ) ;'** Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need more code. I got yelled at last time for putting too much in the description :)

```
pane = new JPanel()
    {


        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Image imgBG = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"bg.jpg");
            g.drawImage(imgBG,0,0,this);

            Image imgCloud = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"cloud.png");
            imgCloud.addMouseListener ( this ) ;
            g.drawImage(imgCloud,intCloudX,0,this);

            Image imgStopLight = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"stop-light.png");
            g.drawImage(imgStopLight,intStopLightX,intStopLightY,this);

            Image imgStopLightAction = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"stop-light-action.jpg");
            g.drawImage(imgStopLightAction,10,170,this);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(395, intLaneMarkerY, intlaneMarkerX, intLaneMarkerY);
            g.setColor(Color.black);

        }

    };
```

Comment: I don't think that `paintComponent` is really the right method in which to be setting up your mouse listener.  This is called each time the window needs to be drawn.  Perhaps you should do all those `getImage` commands outside of this method too.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler's telling you that the `Image` class doesn't have mouse listeners. If you want a mouse listener, you'll need to attach it to whatever component the image is being displayed in, which is probably that `JPanel` itself.